# Can't use variable in php file instead of css

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to use .php file instead of .css to style my code for the first time, but can't get one variable to work.

I'm using $scale variable to determine how big rating scale is going to be, I'm getting good answer (testing it with echo $scale;) But for some reason the height of the div I'm making with $scale doesn't change.This is how I'm getting $scale variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT votes_number, votes_sum FROM lessons WHERE id='$lesson_id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$total_votes   = $row["votes_number"];
$total_upvotes = $row["votes_sum"];
$scale = ceil(100-(($total_upvotes / $total_votes) * 100));
echo $scale;
```

This is the html of the file:

```
<div id='rating_meter'><div><div></div></div></div>
```

CSS(The not working) part:

```
#rating_meter{
background-color:#D3D3D3;
width:5px;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
border-bottom:1px solid #7E7E7E;
}

#rating_meter > div{
background-color:green;
width:5px;
height:180px;
display:inline-block;
}

#rating_meter > div > div{
background-color:red;
width:5px;
display:inline-block;
height:<?php echo $scale;?>%;
}
```

When I use echo $scale; to determine height it always sets the height to 100%, but it echos me 81 to the top of the screen so it should be 81%... When I use number instead of echoing $scale, for example

```
height:73%;
```

Or in the first php file setting $scale like this:

```
$scale = "25";
```

everything works fine...
How could I make my $scale to work as a variable which declares the height of the div?
This problem really took me a lot of time to work with...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file do the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
#rating_meter > div > div{
 height :<?php echo $scale; ?>%;
}

</style>
```

OR

```
<div id='rating_meter' style='height:<?php echo $scale; ?>%'><div><div></div></div></div>
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: The scale goes not from left to right, but from bottom to top.

Comment: FINALLY Your 2nd way of fixing the problem saved me, THANK YOU A MILLION TIMES, I've been stuck on this problem for like 5hours, Thank you very very much!!